# sharing objects between classes and making hierarchy

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

There are four kinds of user types. Admin,Super Moderator, Moderator and Member. Admin can add and delete all kind of user types including admin and can add main topics but he can't upload documents and project. Super moderator can add moderator or member for the any created topic(s). The super moderators can upload and remove documents and projects. The projects have kinds like group project, individual project, deadline. However documents have types as well like pdf(book), ppt(slides), urls. The moderator can be a member in other topic(s) and can view projects related to the topic. Member can enroll the topics wanted and can add projects.

The issue is that here my lack of design oop concept. I can't make the hierarchy. *I really don't want full code* just need ways helping to solve the problem. As far as I can see here just is a relationship between moderator and member. I have programmed in C. But, I haven't been familiar with OOP yet. By the way, I comprehed the logic related to the problem, but I can't write in OOP concept yet. How can it be come up with a solution? I think I need the hierarchy.  Lastly, there could be multiple data accessing because if a member created by admin, it should also be managed by super moderator and interface can be used because of adding and removing by admins and super moderators.

Comment: [composite-design-pattern-java](https://dzone.com/articles/composite-design-pattern-java-0) looks close to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Your use-case is not entirely clear, but if you are trying to model the users and their rights. This might be my first iteration:

Instead of trying to cover everything in one class hierarchy, maybe you could model the different aspects by different classes. I mean: users, rights, actions. User could look like this:

```java
public interface User {
   boolean isAllowed(Action action);
}
```

A right is actually a predicate, a function `Action -> Boolean`:

```java
public interface Right<A extends Action> extends Predicate<A> {
   Class<A> getActionType();
}
```

This thing has a `test(action)` method then which returns a boolean whether given action is allowed. So with this, all 4 types of users should extend this baseclass:

```java
public abstract UserWithRights implements User {
   private final List<Right<?>> rights;

   private UserWithRights(List<Right<?>> rights) {
      ...
   }

   @Override
   public boolean test(Action action) {
      // search for right with same action type and test it
   }
}
```

So the point is, that all users will have a list of rights assigned. I made the list of rights immutable, but you can make it dynamic if it suits you better.

So `admin` would be defined this way:

```java
public class Admin extends UserWithRights {
   public Admin(...) {
      super(asList(
         staticRight(AddUser.class, true),
         staticRight(AddMainTopic.class, true));
      ...
   }
}
```

Those are all static rights because they don't require any parameters from the action. There are however dynamic rights, like a `moderator` is only allowed to view projects on topics she is assigned to:

```java
dynamicRight(ViewProject.class, view -> isAssignedToTopic(view.getTopic()));
```

So anyway, this is maybe how one could start...